# InvalidArgumentError with Keras and WGANs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a critic network as part of a Wasserstein Distance Generative Adversarial Network using the latest Keras package with the Tensorflow backend and python 3.6. This is the code for the network architecture:

```
def build_critic():
    critic = Sequential(name='critic')
    critic.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', 
               kernel_initializer='he_normal', input_shape= 
               (48,48,1),data_format='channels_last'))
    critic.add(LeakyReLU())
    critic.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', 
               kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
    critic.add(LeakyReLU())
    critic.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', 
               kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
    critic.add(LeakyReLU())
    critic.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', 
               kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
    critic.add(LeakyReLU())
    critic.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D(data_format='channels_last'))
    critic.add(Dense(100))
    critic.add(LeakyReLU())
    critic.add(Dense(1))
    return critic
```

When attempting to compile the network, I get the error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [256,48], In[1]: [256,100]
>        [[Node: critic_2/dense_2/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](critic_2/global_max_pooling2d_1/Max, dense_2/kernel/read)]]

I get what the error's complaining about. In order to multiply together two matricies of sizes AxB and CxD, B must equal C, whereas here B=48 and C=256. How can I set C? Or are there other issues I should consider?

Here are the network summaries for the generator and critic networks:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              1049600   
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 1, 1, 1024)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 3, 3, 1024)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 3, 3, 1024)        4096      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2 (None, 12, 12, 1024)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 12, 12, 1024)      4096      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2 (None, 48, 48, 1024)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 128)       1179776   
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 48, 48, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 48, 48, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (Batch (None, 48, 48, 256)       1024      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 1)         2305      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,684,673
Trainable params: 2,679,553
Non-trainable params: 5,120
_________________________________________________________________
None
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 64)        640       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 48, 48, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 48, 48, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 48, 48, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 48, 48, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling2d_1 (Glob (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 100)               25700     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_5 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 543,049
Trainable params: 543,049
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: I guess there is some problem with your data format. Your GlobalMaxPooling2D layer seems to output a 256x48 tensor, while it should output a 1x256 tensor. Seems to me like an error in deciding which axes will be reduced in the max-operation of the max-pooling. Try to find out the default data format via `keras.backend.image_data_format()` and see whether there is a mismatch.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reponse. keras.backend.image_data_format() returns 'channels_last' as expected, and the tensors the network is being batch trained on are of shape (256,48,48,1). Is this a mismatch?

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if you could do two things: First, use another batch size, because 256 is also the number of channels in your last convolution and it would be good to see if the 256 in the [256,48] comes from the batch size or from the convolution channels. Second, print out critic.summary() to see the actual output shapes of the layers.

Comment: Thanks again, it appears that C=256 is being set by the final convolutional layer in the critic network. But now if I change it to 48 such that the previous matrix multiplication ought to work, I get the error in the next comment. The critic and generator .summaries are above.

Comment: [[Node: training/Adam/gradients/critic_2/conv2d_8/convolution_grad/Conv2DBackpropInput = _MklConv2DBackpropInput[T=DT_FLOAT, _kernel="MklOp", data_format="NHWC", padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](training/Adam/gradients/critic_2/conv2d_8/convolution_grad/ShapeN, conv2d_8/kernel/read, training/Adam/gradients/AddN_4, DMT/_119, conv2d_8/kernel/read:1, training/Adam/gradients/AddN_4:1)]]

Comment: C=256 is set by the final convolutional layer, and you do not need to change that, I was concerned about A. Does A change if you change the batch size? It should. And change the output of the final convolutional layer back, the problem is not there,but in AxB

Comment: It does, after changing the batch size to 128, the error message now reads: InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [128,48], In[1]: [256,100].
(I've changed the final convolutional layer back).

Comment: That means that the global max pooling layer will output a tensor of size 48 for each of your input images, however, we would expect a tensor of size 256, as this is the number of channels in the previous layer. I agree that this is strange because in the summary it tells us that the max pooling layer has the expected output size of (None, 128). Please try out the following: Remove the data_format=''channels_last" in both the input and the global max pooling layer and see whether it works, and if not, try to set it as a trial to "channels_first" in pooling, without setting anything in input.

Comment: Removing the data format flag from both the input and pooling layers makes no difference, Using channels first only in pooling yields: InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [128,256], In[1]: [48,100]

Comment: Okay, that is indeed very strange. It seems that now the output of the global max pooling layer is computed correctly, but the Dense layer set its internal transformation matrix [48,100] according to what would be expected by the Keras interface... Which tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: 1.5.0. Oddly, I've just found that if I flatten the images first and do everything in 1D, it works fine, so I'm beginning to think this is some wierd bug in the GlobalMaxPooling2D layer.

Comment: I also think so. You could try to upgrade Tensorflow and/or try out a different Keras version.